# Replacing values in list of dict's (Python) with objects as 'id'

Tags: python, dictionary, tornado

I need to add more values to a list of WSHandler connections (Tornado, Python). I'm adding the connection to a list like so  `self.connections.append(self)`, but I need to add more information, like `self.connections.append({'id': self, 'keyword' : ''})` (and later find the current `self` id and replace the keyword.)

When I try to add to the list based on `self` object (like `self.connections[self].filter = 'keyword'`), I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not WSHandler.`

So how can I do this?

Edit: Managed to find the right object like so:

```
def on_message(self, message):
    print message
    for x in self.connections:
        if x['id'] == self:
            print 'found something'
            x['keyword'] = message
            print x['keyword']
            print x
```

Now, how do I remove the whole dict from `connections` ?        `self.connections.remove(self)` no longer works, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this use case, you do not need a list of connections. It may be easier to store this in the object itself. Simply use `self.filter = 'keyword'`.

Otherwise:

```
for dict in self.connections:
    if dict['id'] == self:
        dict['keyword'] = 'updated'
```

Or, if you favour brevity over clarity:

```
for dict in [dict for dict in self.connections if dict['id'] == self]:
    dict['keyword'] == 'updated'
```

To remove, use:

```
for dict in self.connections:
    if dict['id'] == self:
        self.connections.remove(dict)
```

Comment: Thanks. But it has to match the correct ID in the list of connections. How do I make sure it's the right one?

Comment: Ah yes, I think you're right - easier just storing in the object itself.

Comment: Basically, if the object you are looking for is `self` then there is no need to retrieve it from the connection based on its `id`. In your code fragment you do not show where you store the matching id. Where is that?

Comment: Actually, there is no 'id', it's just my shortname for the self object. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Since `self.connections` is a list, you can only index it using an integer (as the error says). 
`self` here is a WSHandler object, *not* an integer.

I'm not an expert on Tornado, so you should try what Hans says.

If you still need to do it the way you've mentioned, try: `self.connections[self.connections.index(self)]` to locate the self object in the list.